# JTextField in the whole JFrame instead of my determined Area

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

yes I'm a total beginner in Java... Could somebody tell me, why the `JTextField` is located in the whole `JFrame` instead of just the space between (300,50) to (450,75) like I've inputted in `setBounds`?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Chat extends JFrame {

    JTextField t=new JTextField("");

    public Chat() {
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(900, 300);
        t = new JTextField();
        t.setBounds(300, 50, 150, 25);
        add(t);
    }

}
```

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [A visual guide to layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).  They might seem like a strange idea to start with, but they will save your sanity and hair in the long run....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause the JFrame default layout is `BorderLayout` and when you add the components if you don't specify it will put in the center. I recommend to use another layout like
`GridBagLayout`.

Example:

```
public Chat() {
      setSize(900, 300);
      t = new JTextField();
      t.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(x,y));
      GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
      gridBagConstraints.gridx = 6;
      gridBagConstraints.gridy = 7;
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      panel.add(t,gridBagConstraints);
      add(panel);
      pack(); // this sizes the frame
      setVisible(true); // call set visible after adding components
}
```

Should consider read this [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: Thank you, but i got exceptions at the gridBagConstraints: gridBagConstraints cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @user2551736 `GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints` you have to define it, i'll edit

Answer (score 1):

setBounds method works with only with null Layout and default JFrame's layout is BorderLayout. Invoking JFrame's add method with BorderLayout and without specifying location defaults to BorderLayout.CENTER and centers the component, using its maximum size property as bounds. That means that setting prefered size of the component won't work with BorderLayout.CENTER. You can either change the frame's layout to null, using setLayout(null), which is considered a bad practice, because it, among other things, limits portability of the code, or use other layout manager.